# Re-writing mysql statement - select left join alias union join subtraction issue

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, union, alias

I am thinking of the best way to re-write this:

```
SELECT
debits.account_title, debits.total - credits.total AS net_reduction
FROM 
    (
SELECT SUM(a) FROM
(
SELECT SUM(mainaccount_a_2017.amount) AS a FROM `mainaccount_a_2017`
LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_a_2017.joint_account_number)
LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)
WHERE mainaccount_a_2017.dr_cr_action = 'DR' AND asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = 'IN'

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(mainaccount_b_2017.amount) AS a FROM `mainaccount_b_2017`
LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_b_2017.joint_account_number)
LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)
WHERE mainaccount_b_2017.dr_cr_action = 'DR' AND asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = 'IN'
)a
  )AS debits
JOIN
   (
SELECT SUM(a) FROM
(
SELECT SUM(mainaccount_a_2017.amount) AS a FROM `mainaccount_a_2017`
LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_a_2017.joint_account_number)
LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)
WHERE mainaccount_a_2017.dr_cr_action = 'CR' AND asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = 'IN'

UNION ALL

SELECT SUM(mainaccount_b_2017.amount) AS a FROM `mainaccount_b_2017`
LEFT JOIN chart_of_account ON (chart_of_account.joint_account_numbers = mainaccount_b_2017.joint_account_number)
LEFT JOIN asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl ON (asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = chart_of_account.account_type)
WHERE mainaccount_b_2017.dr_cr_action = 'CR' AND asset_liability_income_expenditure_tbl.a_l_code = 'IN'
)a
   )AS credits
ON debits.account_title = credits.account_title
```

Comment: Let us know how you get on

Comment: Hello @Strawberry, I got this error `#1054 - Unknown column 'debits.account_title' in 'field list'` ..This is actually what I want but I know it has to be re-writing cos am not speaking it well enough.

Comment: Please edit your 'question' accordingly. And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And one has to wonder why you have two 'main account' tables

Comment: Also... note that `LEFT JOIN x... WHERE x = ...` is the same as `INNER JOIN x...`

Comment: @Strawberry am doing DEBITS and CREDITS  on the two tables. Here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4uzIxyf_WfVVXFoSFk4NnJXS1U) on my drive with sample data.

Comment: I know. But that's no reason to have two separate 'mainaccount' tables

Comment: @Strawberry Ok, yeah thats true. All entries are unique, am using the PK as reference in another table to comply with the rules of double-entry in accounting. I understand you want to know why I cannot make it happen on same table **one table** but this has solved all the challenges I have been encountering from the beginning of my development until now..I don't know if this makes sense...

Comment: @Strawberry I did the SQL Fiddle it gave me `Table 'db_9_6dbe94.mainaccount_a_2017' doesn't exist` and rextester.com also displayed `Table 'rextester.mainaccount_a_2017' doesn't exist` I know there is a problem thats why am here!

Comment: It may make sense outside of an RDBMS environment, but it doesn't make sense inside one. Further, creating fiddles/rextests that you then keep to yourself isn't very useful. But more than that, I'm sorry to say that there's so much wrong in the query above, that I'm not really sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT B.account_title, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.dr_cr_action = 'CR' THEN A.amount * -1 ELSE A.amount END) AS net_reduction 
FROM (SELECT A.joint_account_number, A.dr_cr_action, A.amount 
      FROM mainaccount_a_2017 A 
     UNION ALL 
      SELECT B.joint_account_number, B.dr_cr_action, B.amount 
      FROM mainaccount_b_2017 B 
     ) AS A 
INNER JOIN chart_of_account B ON A.joint_account_number = B.joint_account_numbers 
WHERE B.account_type = 'IN' 
GROUP BY B.account_title;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a42d8/1):

**::OUTPUT::**

```
|           account_title | net_reduction |
|-------------------------|---------------|
| OTHER GRANTS AND GIFTS  |        301200 |
```

Comment: `#1054 - Unknown column 'B.joint_account_number' in 'field list'`

Comment: @AderogbaOtunla Please check the updated answer. Wrong Alias Given to  second table.

Comment: I am trying to **join** two fields from another table to this: `SELECT B.joint_account_numbers, B.account_title,
       SUM(CASE WHEN A.dr_cr_action = 'CR' THEN A.amount * -1 ELSE A.amount END) AS net_reduction 
FROM (SELECT A.joint_account_number, A.dr_cr_action, A.amount 
      FROM mainaccount_a_2017 A 
     UNION ALL 
      SELECT B.joint_account_number, B.dr_cr_action, B.amount 
      FROM mainaccount_b_2017 B 
     ) AS A 
INNER JOIN chart_of_account B ON A.joint_account_number = B.joint_account_numbers

GROUP BY B.joint_account_numbers`